# Solaar doesn't detect my bluetooth mouse and keyboard on Pop! OS (Works on Fedora)

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, pop-os

On Pop! OS, Solaar does not detect my bluetooth keyboard and mouse (K380, MX Anywhere 2). Running `solaar probe` yields `Exception: Logitech receiver not found`.

If I connect the mouse with the Unifying receiver, it detects it fine. On Fedora, it works great with both bluetooth and Unifying receiver.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the kernel versions in either case? Many drivers are linked to newer kernels. Use `uname -a` to show versions.

Comment: Related: [Ask Ubuntu: How do I install and configure the latest version of `solaar` to manage my Logitech wireless mouse or keyboard on Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1390784/327339)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version in the Pop! OS repos was older. I installed from [here (10.0.4)](https://launchpad.net/%7Esolaar-unifying/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), and it works now.